# Mocking test cases for controller using Mockito

Tags: mocking

I am new to the Mockito test cases. i want to mock the controller which has very simple service listed below.
My Mock test class has an error with wrong attribute passed to mockito  , below is my error

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CreditCardControllerTest {
    @Mock
    private CreditCardService creditCardService;
    @Mock
    Model model;
    Person p;
    @Mock
    CreditCard creditCard ;
    @InjectMocks
    CreditCardController  cc= new CreditCardController();

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        p= new Person();
        creditCard = new CreditCard();
    }

    @Test
    public void m1(){
        assertEquals("add-credit-card",cc.getAdd(p.getId(), model));
        Mockito.verify(model).addAttribute("personId", p.getId());
        Mockito.verify(model).addAttribute("creditCardAttribute", creditCard);
    }
}
```

Below is the error :

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
model.addAttribute(
    "creditCardAttribute",
    org.krams.tutorial.domain.CreditCard@f6c48ac
);
-> at org.krams.tutorial.controller.test.CreditCardControllerTest.m1(CreditCardControllerTest.java:40)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
model.addAttribute(
    "creditCardAttribute",
    org.krams.tutorial.domain.CreditCard@13deb50e
);
-> at org.krams.tutorial.controller.CreditCardController.getAdd(CreditCardController.java:41)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.krams.tutorial.controller.test.CreditCardControllerTest.m1(CreditCardControllerTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

Below is my controller were it adds the credit card details to DB :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main/creditcard")
public class CreditCardController {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");

    @Resource(name="creditCardService")
    private CreditCardService creditCardService;

    /**
     * Retrieves the "Add New Credit Card" page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAdd(@RequestParam("id") Integer personId, Model model) {
        logger.debug("Received request to show add page");

        // Prepare model object
        CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();

        // Add to model
        model.addAttribute("personId", personId);
        model.addAttribute("creditCardAttribute", creditCard);

        // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/add-credit-card.jsp
        return "add-credit-card";
    }
}
```

Below is my credit card class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CREDIT_CARD_OM")
public class CreditCard implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5924361831551833717L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "OMTYPE")
    private String omtype;

    @Column(name = "OMNUMBER")
    private String omnumber;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOmtype() {
        return omtype;
    }

    public void setOmtype(String omtype) {
        this.omtype = omtype;
    }

    public String getOmnumber() {
        return omnumber;
    }

    public void setOmnumber(String omnumber) {
        this.omnumber = omnumber;
    }   
}
```

Can anyone please let me know where it went wrong ?..

finally i got the answer from flup and written the test below ;

```
@Test
    public void m1(){
        assertEquals("add-credit-card",cc.getAdd(p.getId(), model));
        Mockito.verify(model).addAttribute("personId", p.getId());
        //Mockito.verify(model).addAttribute(,creditCard);
        Mockito.verify(model).addAttribute(eq("creditCardAttribute"),isA(CreditCard.class));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocks use the `.equals()` method to determine if a method call matches the expected call. You should override `.equals()` in the `CreditCard` class.

Otherwise it'll default to the `Object.equals()` method which only returns true if the two objects it compares are the same.

And they aren't the same. The expected value is the CreditCard instance you instantiate in your test class. The actual value is the CreditCard instance you instantiate in the controller.

Comment: no , i did not use .equals()  , i tried either changing the mock object to object.. but still error exists.

Comment: What I mean is: you should! (Updated the answer to make it a bit clearer)